# How do I force a secure reboot?

Tags: freeze, reboot

When my Ubuntu freezes, is there a way to force reboot other than to hit the hardware reset button on my computer in order to ensure as best as possible that I don't corrupt any hard drive partition?

EDIT: 
What do I do if I can't even access the terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your local keyboard is working, you can try the "magic keys"

First edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
# Graphical
gksu gedit /etc/sysctl.conf

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add in the line (at the bottom)

```
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

"To perform a safe reboot of a Linux computer, use  RSEIUB magic SysRq Magic combination key:

Hold Alt+PrtSc then type R+S+E+I+U+B , you need to press each key for 2-3 seconds."

http://www.unixmen.com/use-magic-sysrq-combination-key-to-recover-from-a-frozen-system-in-linux-ubuntu/

If you are not getting a response from the local keyboard or mouse, your only other option would be to try to ssh from another box.

You will need to install openssh-server first

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You would then ssh in and shut it down. If you can ssh in, it helps to check the logs as well (before you shut down).

```
ssh user@froxen_box_ip

sudo shutdown -h now
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I believe it's safer to do the sequence REISUB (that's reversed BUSIER), since it flushes fs data AFTER killing the user programs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is better to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to arrive in the terminal (the real frightening one, yes). Then login and launch `sudo reboot`. That's a better way than just pushing the restart button.

But before rebooting, you may want to kill the problematic process. Type `ps -ejH` in the terminal to list the current processes. Spot which one is problematic (let's arbitrarily take the example of `banshee`). Then type `killall banshee`. Go back into your graphical interface by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.